# Is the fingerprint template generated by the vendor-specific library or the sensor?

Tags: fingerprint

My understanding based on the online resources is that there is a vendor-specific fingerprint library running in the TEE which is responsible for communicating to the fingerprint sensor hardware as well as enrollment, matching, ... of fingerprints.

What is unclear to me is what the sensor's output is? Does it generate the fingerprint template, or it sends just the raw fingerprint data to the library and the template is generated by the library?

Comment: I would assume that the finger print sensors are pretty dumb and just send the raw data to the TEE. See also https://source.android.com/security/authentication/fingerprint-hal#implementation

Comment: Yes I've seen this page, but even this page doesn't say where the template is generated.

Comment: best is to follow `enroll()` in sources down to the rabbit hole, don't you think?

Comment: It is not specified, but as only the TEE and the fingerprint driver has access to the raw fingerprint data the template generation has to be performed in one of them (or directly in the fingerprint sensor).